# Query method in Spring Data JPA for relation @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.forumProject.Authentication.Repository.PostRepository.findByTags(java.util.List,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on tags requires a scalar argument, found interface java.util.List in method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.example.forumProject.Authentication.Repository.PostRepository.findByTags(java.util.List,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable).

This is the Post class defined:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "posts", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "title" }) })
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Post extends UserDateAudit {
    ... 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    Page<Post> findByCreatedBy(Long userId, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Post> findByCategory(Long categoryId, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Post> findByTags(List<Tag> tags, Pageable pageable);

    Long countByCreatedBy(Long userId);
}
```

Comment: You should rename (fix) your method name findByTags to findByTagsIsIn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want Dynamic Queries with Spring Data JPA Specifications with `In` clause

We need to use the keyword `In` in our method name as shown below.

```
Page<Post> findByTagsIn(List<Tag> tags, Pageable pageable);
```

You can find all Supported keywords inside method names [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.definition)